# python map() on zipped object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I have two inputs lists `a` and `b` and a function which takes two inputs, let's say

```
def f(x, y): return x*y
```

How do I use `map()` for this setup? I tried

```
map(f, zip(a,b))
```

and got

> TypeError: f() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

It makes sense because I need to unpack the zipped input. How can I do that?

Comment: `map(f, a, b)`.

Comment: `def f(x): return x[0]*x[1]`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`map` doesn't unpack the iterables as your function argument, but instead as a more general way for dealing with such problems you can use [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) function from `itertools` module which should be used instead of `map()` when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable:

```
from itertools import starmap

starmap(f, zip(a,b))
```

Here is an example:

```
In [2]: a = range(5)

In [3]: b = range(5, 10)

In [7]: from itertools import starmap

In [8]: list(starmap(f, zip(a,b)))
Out[8]: [0, 6, 14, 24, 36]
```

As another option your can just pass the iterables to map separately without zipping them.

```
In [13]: list(map(mul, a, b))
Out[13]: [0, 6, 14, 24, 36]
```

Also as a more pythonic way for multiplying two variable you can use `operator.mul()` instead of creating a custom function:

```
In [9]: from operator import mul

In [10]: list(starmap(mul, zip(a,b)))
Out[10]: [0, 6, 14, 24, 36]
```

Here is the benchmark:

```
In [11]: %timeit list(starmap(mul, zip(a,b)))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 838 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit list(starmap(f, zip(a,b)))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **lambda** function to handle this situation where:

```
Map(lambda (x,z): function(x,z), zip(listA, listB))
```

I know this is an old post but probably will help somebody else in future.

PD: Sorry any typo I'm from my phone.

Comment: Tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python 3.